# Dynamically create Hash and Arrays

Tags: ruby, syntactic-sugar

I am looking for the Ruby-est way to solve a problem.

I have code of a form similar to this in my application:

```
data = [1,2,3,4]
a = []
b = []
h = {}
data.each do |val|
  h[val] = func1(val)
  a.push func2(val)
  b.push func3(val)
end
```

This is, of course, a simplification. What I'd like to do, given code like this, is to eliminate lines 2-4 of this snippet, so that I have something like:

```
 h, a, b = data.some_func{|val|
   # do something
 }
```

My instinct is that `map` won't be enough, but I'm not sure what I need instead. My code works, but it doesn't look very rubyish. What should I be doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's not exactly what you're asking for, but at least it's readable:

```
data = [1,2,3,4]
h = data.each_with_object({}) { |e, m| m[e] = func1(e) }
a = data.map &method(:func2)
b = data.map &method(:func3)
```

Though, as you said, your example is a simplification of a real task, so it might not work for you. In that case I'd recommend to stay with your original solution.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will be using something similar to it, I'm pretty sure. I probably oversimplified my example - in the actual code, a and b are initialized based on references to what's in h, so I think each_with_object on h followed by creation of a and b will remove the empty inits without hurting readability.

Answer (score 2):

I think my example isn't the best but... you can decide

```
h, a, b = data.each_with_object([ {}, [], [] ]) do |val, obj|
  obj[0][val] = func1 val
  obj[1] << func2(val)
  obj[2] << func3(val)
end
```

**EDIT**: This is pretty hard to read unless you understand [each_with_object](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object) ... perhaps your initial solution is the best approach.

Comment: No offense, but this is horrible. Though, looks like that's what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @KL-7 I agree. I wouldn't do it this way. Just answering the OP's question.

Comment: Would you be willing to elaborate on what makes it horrible? I'm asking to learn, so if my approach is way off, I'd much rather a new approach than something which achieves a bad goal.

Comment: @asfallows, your solution in the question has these explicit arrays initializations, that might not look cool enough, but it's pretty easy to understand what you're trying to achieve. Provided solution eliminates explicit initialization, but it's not very clear why do you call `each_with_object` with such meme. In addition, if you add more code in the block it'll be pretty easy to get lost in these `obj[0]`, `obj[1]`, and `obj[2]`.

Comment: Exactly. If you want to build another array, you have 2 spots to edit and potentially screw up!